# GA4 Measurement Protocol + cURL

Tags: php, google-analytics-4

The platform does not support the insertion of scripts or GTMs.
So I'm going to collect information with GA4 through image insertion.
GA4 Measurement Protocol and curl are trying to collect information, but no information is collected.

The PHP source code is as below, what is the problem?
If you take a response, there's nothing in it
If you take an httpcode, 204 is output.
There is no response from Google Analytics's real-time dashboard.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$data = array(
    'client_id' => time(),
    'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
);

$event = array(
    'name' => 'view_item',
    'params' => array(
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'item_id' => 'NS',
                'item_name' => 'NSbarm'
            )
        ),
        'currency' => 'KRW',
        'value' => 14500,
        'user_id' => '12345'
    )
);

$body = array(
    'non_personalized_ads' => false,
    'events' => array($event)
);
$body = json_encode($body);

$url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?api_secret=g000000000w&measurement_id=G-47000000';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) {
    $img_name="./line.png";
    $source_im=ImageCreateFromPNG($img_name);
    $target_im=ImageCreateTrueColor(750,10);
    $white=ImageColorAllocate($target_im,0,0,0);

    ImageCopyResampled($target_im,$source_im,0,0,0,0,750,10,750,10);
    ImagePNG($target_im);

    ImageDestroy($source_im);
    ImageDestroy($target_im);
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo "Error sending data to Google Analytics";
}
?>
```